# how to give mongodb socketkeepalive in spring boot application?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

In spring boot if we want to connect to mongodb, we can create a **configuration** file for mongodb or writing datasource in **application.properties**

I am following the second way

For me, I am gettint this error

```
"Timeout while receiving message; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message
```

.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017/admin
```

I am gettint this error If I am not using my app for 6/7 hours and after that If I try to hit any controller to retrieve data from Mongodb. After 1/2 try I am able to get

Question - **Is it the normal behavior of mongodb?**
So, in my case it is closing the socket after some particular hours

I read some blogs where it was written you can give **[socket-keep-alive](https://api.mongodb.com/java/2.6/com/mongodb/MongoOptions.html)**, so the connection pool will not close

In spring boot mongodb connection, we can pass options in uri like

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017/admin/?replicaSet=test&connectTimeoutMS=300000
```

So, I want to give **socket-keep-alive** options for spring.data.mongodb.uri like replicaset here.

I searched the [official site](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.authSource), but can't able to find any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve to pass this option using [MongoClientOptionsFactoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoClientOptionsFactoryBean.html).

```
public MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions() {
    try {
        final MongoClientOptionsFactoryBean bean = new MongoClientOptionsFactoryBean();
        bean.setSocketKeepAlive(true);
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return bean.getObject();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new BeanCreationException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Here an example of this configuration by extending [AbstractMongoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/config/AbstractMongoConfiguration.html):

```
@Configuration
public class DataportalApplicationConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    //@Value: inject property values into components
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private String uri;
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String database;

    /**
     * Configure the MongoClient with the uri
     *
     * @return MongoClient.class
     */
    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(uri,mongoClientOptions().builder()));
    }
```

Comment: Can I get any example code of this type of config? As I can not able to proceed how to use it in my Application. I am using mongo repository for my spring-boot. Can I use repository if I will use MongoClientOptionsFactoryBean  bean??

Comment: did not check till now. Busy with work so much. I will let you know. But, 1 thing to ask, is it normal behaviour of mongodb to go idle if not used? If yes, then in production mode do they do socket-keep-alive?

Comment: You can try with `socket-keep-alive` function but I'm not sure that will solve your issue. I have a SpringBoot application connected to a MongoDB ReplicaSet. This application is pretty much not used and I've never experienced timeout exception.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I have heard from other 1/2 peoples same thing which you said. They have not used socket-keep-alive

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by providing a MongoClientOptions bean. Spring Data's MongoAutoConfiguration will pick this MongoClientOptions bean up and use it further on:

```
@Bean
public MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions() {
    return MongoClientOptions.builder()
            .socketKeepAlive(true)
            .build();
}
```

Also note that the socket-keep-alive option is deprecated (and defaulted to true) since mongo-driver version 3.5 (used by spring-data since version 2.0.0 of spring-data-mongodb)